# Memory managment in Ray (multiprocessing python)

Tags: python, memory-management, multiprocessing, ray

I am trying to parallelize a loop **for** with a list of videos, where I process them, extracting several features and metadata from each video. My code is as shown below:

```
ray.init(num_cpus=8)

ids = [self.process_video.remote(self, v=v, dataset=dataset, m=m, verb=verb) for v in self.videoIdx]

not_ready = [1, 2]
while len(not_ready) != 0:
    ready, not_ready = ray.wait(ids[0], num_returns=12, timeout=None)

for i in range(len(ids)):
    if ray.get(ids[i][0]) == 1:
         outliers.append(ray.get(ids[i][1]))
    res.newDataSerie()
    res.addData('method', m)
    res.addData('dataset', dataset.name)
    res.addData('videoIdx', ray.get(ids[i][1]))
    res.addData('videoFilename', ray.get(ids[i][2]))
    res.addData('sigFilename', ray.get(ids[i][3]))
    res.addData('featureGT', ray.get(ids[i][4]))
    res.addData('timeGT', ray.get(ids[i][5]))
    res.addData('featureES', ray.get(ids[i][6]))
    res.addData('timeES', ray.get(ids[i][7]))
    res.addData('RMSE', ray.get(ids[i][8]))
    res.addData('PCC', ray.get(ids[i][9]))

ray.shutdown()
```

Before running the previous code, I have tried it also **without** using the method *wait()*. The result is the same in both case, but both, different when the code is executed sequentially without any type of parallelization. Those RMSE, PCC metrics change when using the Ray Library to parallelize it, and not when using for instance, the *multiprocessing.pool* approach.

The function **process_video()** starts like this:

```
 @ray.remote(num_returns=10, memory=1000 * 1024 * 1024)
 def process_video(self, v, dataset, m, verb):
```

I am using *Ray* in a simple desktop. The purpose is not to do distributed computing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should learn to use `for item in ids: ...` and your code will be more readable.

Comment: Thanks @furas for your comment, but if I am not wrong, I made it like that because "the object *ids* is not iterable". But I will check it later.

Comment: if you can do `ids[0]` then it should work with `for`-loop